# How do I get NSOpenPanel to populate a TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a app for macOS and I have a button that runs a function to open Finder and select a folder. Below is the code for the function which is borrowed from Stack Overflow:

```
func showChooseFileDialog(){
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.prompt = "OK"
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
            if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                let selectedPath = openPanel.url!.path

                // fill the TextField with the selectedPath?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have the function or button populate a TextField using SwiftUI.

Comment: Set a `@State` variable that is used as the `@Binding` for the `TextField`

Comment: The problem is that I don't know exactly where to put the @State variable to make it work.  Suggestions?

Comment: You haven't included any code from your App, so no, it's impossible to give suggestions on where it should go.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me with `(get:set:)`.  Also changed `self.selectedPath = openPanel.url` in your method.

```
struct PathTextField: View {
    @State private var selectedPath: URL? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("path name", text: Binding<String>(
                get: { selectedPath?.path(percentEncoded: true) ?? "" },
                set: { _ in }
            ))
            .padding(15)
            // Read only TextField option
            //.disabled(true) 

            Button(action: showChooseFileDialog) {
                Text("Select Path")
            }
        }
    }

    func showChooseFileDialog() {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.prompt = "OK"
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
            if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                self.selectedPath = openPanel.url
            }
        }
    }
}
```